# Calling methods from module in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

How should I fill the fruit class so that the below code works? I am not able to figure out how to call the printArgument method in Fruit class

```
module MyModule
  def printArgument(fruit)
    print "from MyModule, printArgument: "
    puts "argument supplied is #{fruit}"
  end
end


class Fruit
  #FILL ME OUT 


end


s = Fruit.new(10)
s.printArgument s.weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implements `Fruit`:

```
class Fruit
  include MyModule

  attr_accessor :weight

  def initialize(weight)
    @weight = weight
  end
end
```

The line `include MyModule` extends the class with the behaviour of `MyModule`. This is what is known as a mix-in. The rest merely creates a property `weight` and makes it publicly accessible.